# Is my Ubuntu install 32 or 64-bit?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, 64-bit, 32-bit, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to find out if my Ubuntu install is 32 or 64-bit. 
The best I can find is "i686" does this mean its 32 bit?

What's the correct way of finding out if the Ubuntu installed on my laptop is 32 or 64-bit?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go into the terminal and type in.

```
uname -a
```

If your results are similar to the one below, then yours is 64-bit; otherwise, it is 32-bit.

```
Linux ubuntu-tm 2.6.35-28-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 14:39:03 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If you have the **x86_64** then your machine is 64-bit.

If your results are similar to this one; then you have 32-bit.

```
Linux Server 2.6.15-23-386 #1 SMP Tue Mar 1 13:49:40 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Notice the **i686** in the code, that means your machine is 32-bit.

UPDATE:

Type in the following in the terminal;

```
uname -m
```

It will give you either **x86_64**, which is 64-bit, or something else, which is 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

`uname -a`

_64 will mean that its 64 bit. otherwise its 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can type:

```
file /sbin/init
```

The result is easy to read. For example, on one particular 32-bit system, I got:

> ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
>   dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
>   BuildID[sha1]=0x07075fcb55b05aeb6286efabba63534fa6ecd213, stripped

So, either way, you will find what you need.