# Is my install 32 or 64bit?

Tags: x86, 64-bit, ubuntu-12.04, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)
>   [Is my install 32 or 64bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/260993/is-my-install-32-or-64bit)

I'm trying to find out if my Ubuntu install is 32 or 64bit.

Whats the best way of finding out if the Ubuntu installed on my laptop is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: `uname -a` will tell you. If it says anything along the lines of `amd64`, it's a 64-bit distro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu can simply try like this:-

```
1)    uname -a
```

or

```
2)    file /sbin/init
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways finding it:

- The first one is the way mentioned above by typing "**uname-a**" in terminal.
- You can also type "**lsb_release -a**" which will give you the info you want.
- If you want a "GUI option" then you can use either gnome system monitor or system settings.
  Search for "**system monitor**" in your apps and in the tab "**System**" you will also see this.Finally you can search for "**system settings**" and inside it you can find what you want from the "**System info**" option.

Answer (score 1):

in the terminal window, type

> uname –m

and hit enter.

if the response is i686, you have a 32-bit version of Linux.
if the response is x86_64, you have a 64-bit version of Linux.

in advance if you get some other value like i386, you almost certainly have a 32-bit version of Linux.

You can find out more detail via

> uname –a

about your particular installation of Linux, like your kernel version,